# ArrayList being returned but recieving a null pointer?

Tags: java

Assuming I have two methods. One that creates an arraylist and returns it, the other retrieving that list to process. both methods are in different classes:

```
public ArrayList getSocialUsers() throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///socialsystemtest1?user=root&password=");
    Statement stmt= null;
    String query="SELECT FORE_NAME FROM socialsystemtest1.socialworkers";
    stmt= conn.createStatement();
    ArrayList<String> socialWorkers= new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String user= rs.getString("Fore_Name");
            socialWorkers.add(user);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        //do nothing
    }
    finally{
        if(stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }

    return socialWorkers;

}

public void processArray(){
  try{
    ArrayList<String>= db.getSocialUsers();
    //code ommitted
  }
  catch(SQLException e){
    //deal with it here
  }
}
```

db is an instance of the class that returns the arraylist already instantiated. I recieve a null pointer error at the first line of the second classes method: `db.getSocialUsers();`

when calling the `getSocialUsers()` method on its own this works and an `ArrayList` is indeed returned with the correct elements but when calling it from another class gives a null pointer and I don't know why

Comment: The line that gives the NPE does not compile. What is the actual code?

Comment: where did you instantiated db ?

Comment: are you sure that db is not null?

Comment: Where is the List object here  ArrayList<String>= db.getSocialUsers();
 ?

Comment: Don't you forgot to initialise the `db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the `db` object is `null`, not the `ArrayList`. Where are you instantiating it?

**Edit**: I recommend you replace the instantiation in the constructor with a member initialization:

```
public class Admin {
    Database db = new Database();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I am instantiating the db object in the constructor of the second class.

Comment: Database db;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Admin
     */
    public Admin()
    {
        createView();
        db= new Database();
    }

Answer (score 1):

If a line

```
ArrayList<String> array = db.getSocialUsers();
```

causes a NullPointerException, this can only be a result of `db` being `null`. You should check if the database is opened and the reference is stored in `db`

Answer (score 0):

make `ArrayList<String> socialWorkers` a field in the first class. Check that your `db` object is not null.

Answer (score 0):

In your second class where you have `processArray` how are you initializing `db`. As per your post it seems that `db` is null hence it throws NPE.

Make sure you have initialized `db`

Your code in `processArray` should be like this:

```
ArrayList<String> valuesFromDB = db.getSocialUsers();
```

Though better programming will always ask you to do like this :

```
List<String> valuesFromDB = db.getSocialUsers();
```

And your `getSocialUsers` should return `List` instead of `ArrayList` like:

```
public List<String> getSocialUsers() throws SQLException
```